# How can I debug a C++ executable that is called externally

Tags: c++, debugging, fortran, executable

I looked online for a solution to this and I would assume this could be done but I cannot seem to find a feasible way of doing this. I have inherited some source code that builds into a executible. The executible consists of C++ and an Fortran library. The file is placed in a simulator enviroment where another program calls the executable. I need to debug some logic errors. The executible cannot run unless the other program calls it. How can I have the other program call it and still access the features of the VS debugger.

MJR

Comment: Did either of these answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

VS Debugger has `Debug -> Attach to process`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood well your question you need to go in VS in 
Debug-->Attach to Process